# How do I tell what type of RAM I have in Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, ram

I have a dual-boot system with both Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Windows normally provides me detailed system information like what type of RAM is used. However, I am currently troubleshooting the PC and I cannot currently use Windows. How can I find out using Ubuntu what type of RAM I is being used (DDR2, DDR3, etc.)? Please keep in mind it does not state what type on the RAM cards themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can type the following commands in the terminal

`sudo su`

`dmidecode --type 17`

you will then see your RAM properties displayed... bingo!
Hope this helps you.